# Change kwarg defaults

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection, python-internals

Given a function that takes `**kwargs`, I want to dynamically set defaults values for those keyword arguments. Is it possible to do that in Python 2.7 and Python 3?

In code, I want `set_kw_defaults` such that:

```
def f(**kwargs):
    print kwargs 
    # in practice, much complicated black-box processing happens
    # here; printing the kwargs is just an example

set_kw_defaults(f, {'magic': 'is possible'})

f()
```

prints:

```
{'magic': 'is possible'}
```

I know how to accomplish this kind of dynamic arg-default rewriting for positional arguments, and for Python 3 / [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) "keyword only" arguments. I also know how to build decorators to wrap `f` and intercept / modify kwargs. That's *not* what I want here. I want to set defaults for arbitrary kwargs that were not conceived when `f` was defined, and I can't decorate `f`. With those constraints, is `set_kw_defaults` possible?

To clarify: `f` is not a function for which I can modify the source code or decorate. For better or worse, it already takes its arguments as `**kwargs`. This is not a normal argument passing issue, but a oddball outlier. I'm looking for assistance from those who understand the internals of Python argument passing.

Clarification re decoration: I cannot decorate or wrap `f`, because decoration and wrapping creates a new object (call it `f2`) which is called as a proxy for the original `f`. Whether done with the `@decorator` syntax, a simple functional wrap, or a class-based scheme, they all boil down to:

```
def f2(**kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('color', 'green')
    f(**kwargs)
```

But if other parts of the running system already point to `f`, they will be unaffected by my creation of `f2`. If it were positional arguments or kw-only arguments I needed to change the default values for, I could do that in the original `f` object, and all users of `f` would get the new defaults. If I decorate, that's not the case.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about setting defaults for "arbitrary kwargs that were not conceived when `f` was defined". If you have the argument you want to set in mind (like your `{'magic': 'is possible'}`), you could rather write your function line like `def f(magic='is possible', **kwargs)`. If not, how do you come up with the keys for your `dict` you pass to hypothetical `set_kw_defaults`?

Comment: There's no way to do that.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I believe the op wants to set a default value for all `**kwargs` arguments.

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto If that's the correct interpretation then you could create a defaultdict inside the function and update your kwargs into it. I don't wanna post that as an answer until we get a clarifying update because I'll just get downvoted if the question changes.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I understand how to set default values for parameters and such. If `f` were a function I could rewrite, that'd be great. `f` is not a function I can modify or decorate, however. For better or worse, it already takes its arguments in the style it's going to take them.

Comment: @JonathanEunice Why can't you modify or decorate it? You're literally asking to modify it (modify how it handles kwargs), yet saying you can't modify it. You can't modify something without modifying it.

Comment: I cannot modify the source code for `f`.  I have the function object that results, which I can inspect and modify in any way Python allows dynamic function objects to be modified, but I cannot change the original source code or the way `f` takes its parameters.

Comment: @JonathanEunice That's what I thought you meant, which means you can decorate it. Decorating functions does not modify the source code. Adding `@decorator` to a function is just syntactic sugar. You have to wrap the function in something (a function, a callable class, etc) that does what you want, calls the original function with the modifications, and returns whatever. `f = decorator(f)`

Comment: I cannot decorate it even *post hoc*, because decoration creates a new object (call it `f2`) which is called as a proxy for the original `f`. But if other parts of the running system already have pointers to `f`, they will be unaffected by my creation of `f2`. If it were positional arguments or kw-only arguments I needed to change the default values for, I could do that in the original `f` object, and all users of `f` would get the new defaults. If I decorate, not the case.

Comment: You could monkey patch `f` to wrap it in something else that calls the original `f`

Comment: What do you _mean_ "other parts of the system already point to f"? You're obfuscating so many of the details of this mystery system and odd request (why are you doing this anyway?) that the goalposts keep moving. Are you saying that even if you modify `f` in your local namespace, something from somewhere else will just reimport it and not have your changes?

Comment: Noting is obfuscated, and no goal posts have moved. The constraint of 1/ not modifying the source code and 2/ not wrapping or decorating the function were in the question from the get-go. I specifically tried to avoid this flurry of "you should write the function differently" or "just wrap the function" answers, which are non-responsive to the clearly-stated constraints. Yes, other modules are calling `f`, before my code ever has a chance to run. I can change my local references; other code will still hold pointers to the original `f` object.

Comment: @JonathanEunice _Calling_ f or _importing_ f? If they're calling it before your code even runs, then of course you can't modify it. If they're _importing_ it, then it remains to be seen why you can't monkey-patch, modify, or decorate it. You would just have to dynamically modify their namespace to use your monkey-patched `f`.

Comment: Most systematic intercepts seem to require a call such as `gevent.monkey.patch_socket()` before user code starts. Not sure how to search through all namespaces to find all references to `f`--or, given that some of those might be embedded in local objects the structure of which I don't know--whether that's realistic or feasible. "just have to" doesn't seem to capture the challenge of doing that reliability. Monkey patching `f` itself, if feasible, seems more direct and reliable.

Comment: Can you load your code before any other code in the system that might take a reference to `f`?  Because if so, you can just replace it in the `import package.containing.f; f.f = decorate(f.f)` ... otherwise, as you note in your answer, I don't think this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

I've come to believe this cannot be done in Python.

I reasoned that if default values are stored for normal positional arguments (and in Python 3, for keyword-only arguments) that function definitions might have an internal dict that stored these mappings. That dict might be amenable to modification.

But it doesn't appear to be that simple. In Python 2, though arguments with default values look like kwarg values, they aren't really. Default values are stored in a tuple that's matched to positional arguments. With a `dis.dis` disassembly, I found that references to these positional arguments are pretty deeply embedded into the bytecode, even when there are default values.

In Python 3 the situation is slightly better, given that there are "keyword only" arguments, and default values are indeed stored as a dict. That dict is modifiable. So that is a sliver of success. *But* modifying values for kwargs that are not pre-known as keyword-only variables does not work; those "extra" values are ignored.

Long story short, default values are not generally stored in a nicely modifiable dict form, and the only cases where they are stored in a modifiable dict do not appear to be broad enough to achieve the "default value monkey patching" I'd hoped for.

Several respondents suggested modifying the original source code (not possible here) or decorating the function / adding a front-end proxy to it that twiddles the kwarg parameters. While that would in many situations be exactly right, that I am integrating into a complex existing application means that I'd have to search the pre-existing Python object space for references to the original function and replace them with references to the proxy. That kind of exhaustive search might be possible in some circumstances, but seems dicey in the general case. Finding some existing references to `f` and replacing them with references to `f2` might be useful, but I don't see how it could be done for all possible references. It is likely to also require an extensive memory-walk. Another intrusive approach might be to dynamically rewrite the bytecode. In theory it might work...but I'm not confident in it.

Because Python's function default parameters do not seem amenable to the type of dynamic setting I'd asked about, even after significant poking around the bytecode, disassembler, `inspect` module, and other places, I'm going to declare this "can not accomplish" and move on.

Thanks everyone for the discussion and ideas.

Comment: you said you can't modify the original source, however, you could write your patches in a new file that imports the original source, makes your modifications (and calls the new function the same), and then change your PYTHONPATH so that all references to the existing function call your modified version (the calling functions should be none the wiser)

Comment: Um... maybe. But complex reorganization of imports and `PYTHONPATH` are unlikely to be clean, simple, and/or robust for complex code bases. I could also used bytecode and/or AST rewriting to accomplish this. The same complexity and robustness downsides, however, still apply.

Comment: You might be able to get away with making 2 modifications: 1) the new file as described in my previous comment 2) in the `__init__.py` inside the module where the original `f` resides, set up the import to the file created in step 1, and kick out the original reference, so that all calls of `module_foo.f()` and `from module_foo import f` end up with your modified f.   The complexity of this solution shouldn't need to scale with the number of function invocations, or the complexity of the codebase.